# Dynamic object creation with Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I am not that skilled with `Retrofit` library and I ran into a problem that i don't know how to handle without restructuring the whole project.

Basically, i have two responses that are very similar, but my code only handles one response.

Here are the responses and what i did, so tell me if there is any way to do this...

```
{  
"cv":[  
  {  
     "id":46,
     "name":"Ciriculum Vitae",
     "description":"Lorem ipsum description is the best description one can write down",
     "file":"1482915089-test-test-cv1.pdf",
     "file_url":"http://xxxyy/file/46/1482915089-test-test-cv1.pdf",
     "type":"cv"
  },
  ...
],
"diploma":[  
  {  
     "id":52,
     "name":"dasdasdasdsa",
     "description":"Random description",
     "institution_name":"hello",
     "completed_date":"12.12.2016.",
     "file":"1482918005-test-test-dasdasdasdsa.pdf",
     "file_url":"http://xxxyy/file/52/1482918005-test-test-dasdasdasdsa.pdf",
     "type":"diploma"
  }
],
... 
"certification":[  
  {  
     "id":50,
     "name":"Certificate of Greatness",
     "description":"I have been great at many things so everybody diecided to give me a certificate for it.",
     "institution_name":"Certification 3",
     "validation_date":"10.06.2017.",
     "file":"1482917772-test-test-dasdasdasdsa.pdf",
     "file_url":"http://xxxyy/file/50/1482917772-test-test-dasdasdasdsa.pdf",
     "type":"certification"
  }
],
...
 }
```

Okay this is just a sample, but you can clearly see that these are some documents that have their types. There are 17 types of documents each with different fields.

Logically, I've created 17 different models `cv` model, `diploma` model, etc...

The problem arises later in the project when i want to fetch documents that are related to a single candidate, the response then is like so:

`Response2`

```
 "documents": [
      {
        "id": 46,
        "name": "Ciriculum Vitae",
        "type": "cv",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum description is the best description one can write down",
        "file": "1482915089-test-test-cv1.pdf",
        "file_url": "http://xxxyy/file/46/1482915089-test-test-cv1.pdf"
      },
      {
         "id":52,
         "name":"dasdasdasdsa",
         "description":"Random description",
         "institution_name":"hello",
         "completed_date":"12.12.2016.",
         "file":"1482918005-test-test-dasdasdasdsa.pdf",
         "file_url":"http://xxxyy/file/52/1482918005-test-test-dasdasdasdsa.pdf",
         "type":"diploma"
      },
      {
        "id": 50,
        "name": "Certificate of Greatness",
        "type": "certification",
        "description": "I have been great at many things so everybody diecided to give me a certificate for it.",
        "file": "1482917772-test-test-dasdasdasdsa.pdf",
        "file_url": "http://xxxyy/file/50/1482917772-test-test-dasdasdasdsa.pdf"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Now obviously the field 'type' is the type of object that needs to be created. But so far i don't know how to make my models fit into this 2nd response.

What should i do here, guys?

In case you're wondering what my code looks like, here it is...

```
@SerializedName("cv")
@Expose
private List<Cv> cv = null;
...
@SerializedName("diploma")
@Expose
private List<Diploma> diploma = null;
...
@SerializedName("certification")
@Expose
private List<Certification> certification = null;
```

**EDIT**
Actually what i wanted to do is create object dependent on the 'type' parameter and fill it with info i get from the response.

How will i go about doing this?

Comment: You can create a `Document` class and have all the other types derive from it. Use inheritance to abstract out all the common logic in the super class.

Comment: @akash93 I actually need to create an object because that's the way my app is structured. I need specific document, can't have abstractions.

Comment: Maybe look into creating a custom JSON parser for retrofit that checks the type of the JSON objects and creates objectes depending on that type.

Comment: @NielsMasdorp yeah, thanks :)